# Which layout actually displays a contact in list view?

Tags: android, contacts

I'd like to modify the contact photo in Contacts List View to a smaller resolution. But I cannot seem to find the layouts that defines a list view entry. I've trudged through the code but it's a huge labyrinth of layouts. Does anyone know which one it might be?

Comment: Post the layout that and supporting code here.

Comment: ListView item layouts are created based on the view desired. Contacts will have a layout for a listview, bookmarks another layout, text messages another.. etc. Maybe look into creating your own layout that suits your needs instead of trying to use an existing one that might not be exactly what you need

Comment: dymmeh: That's the goal but I cannot find WHERE the layouy is inflated so I can put in my own custom layout name. There are so many layouts in Contacts, it is tough to figure out which one I need to clone and modify.

Comment: coder_For_Life22: That's the problem, I cannot find which layout renders a list view item. Once I can find that I am guessing I can find where it's inflated and insert my modified layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for me it worked...

Use a `custom adapter`, by `extending a class to BaseAdapter`. You can create the view to be displayed on the listView of your choice by this method.

Any class which extends to BaseAdapter will implement 4 methods, `getCount, getItem,` `getItemId, getView`

Comment: Is ContactEntryListAdapter the adapter that is used to display the contacts in list view?

Comment: what you are asking is possible more efficiently using a custom adapter. ContactEntryListAdapter is the Common base class for various contact-related lists, e.g. contact list, phone number list etc.

Comment: I am not sure where to find which layout displays an entry in the list view. Do you know which one it is?

Comment: Are you saying I can't simply modify a layout and instead need to create a custom adapter?

Comment: If you are going to use a ListView to display information, then it can have only one textView in it...but if you want more flexibility like phone nos, mobile nos, name etc to be displayed for every contact, u must use custom adapters.

Comment: Correct. I want to modify the default textView so that the contact photos are smaller. That is all I am trying to do. A custom adapter seems a bit overkill for such a small task.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11889/discussion-between-gdanko-and-kumar-vivek-mitra)